# teacher permisions on class-onenote

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I am teaching in a school that uses onenote.

For one of my classes there is a class onenote (setup using class onenote), set up by another teacher.
The other teacher has added me to the onenote.
All I can see is the Welcome section (like it is new).
I added a section, the pupils and other teacher can see this. When I work with the pupils, I can see on their screens that they have other sections. I have tried to talk with the other teacher, about the lack of permissions, but he does not listen.

Does anyone have any ideas what they may have done wrong, when they gave me teacher permissions? (I am sure if I had access to their account, I could fix it, so asking people with more insight, and experience, if you know.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong.

The other teacher sent me “proof” that they had given me permissions. This showed me that they had used the regular one-note permissions, not the class-onenote wizard.

So I used my best diplomacy, to help them to give me the permission that I need.

In summary. Class onenote is very usefull, but a hack. It is a set of wizards, for setting up onenote, adding teachers, and adding pupils. It is not an alternative version of onenote. This can lead to confusion.